How to calculate total torque in BLDC with 6 step commutation
I have the back EMF constant while trying to estimate the torque from BLDC. In the literature, this is given by the sum of the torque for the 3 phases which is obtained from the product of the back EMF constant and the current. However, this value is zero due to the sum of the current in the 3 phases being zero. How do I get the torque then?

Do you happen to know the peak current for each phase?
